# WCF Upload Blob in Azure Local Storage Account

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

I'm currently working on a WCF Rest web service with C# and Azure Storage where i need to upload file in the Local Storage Account. At this time, i have been able to upload a specific file in a specific container, but, i need to be able to choose any file in my computer and upload it on the container of my choice.

Here the upload code in the service:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "UploadBlob", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public void UploadBlob()
{
    // Connect to the storage account's blob endpoint 
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("BlobConnectionString"));
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

    // Create the blob storage container 
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");
    container.CreateIfNotExists();

    // Create the blob in the container 
    CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("nature");

    using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"C:\Image\nature.jpg"))
    {
        blob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
    }
}
```

Here i am uploading the "nature.jpg" file in the "mycontainer" container. 
In my web form, i am using the following code to call the method once the button is clicked:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BlobService upload = new BlobService();
    upload.UploadBlob();
}
```

Here is the design code with my button and file upload input:

```html
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Upload" />
```

When i click this button, the nature.jpg is uploaded. What i need is to be able to choose a file on my computer and upload it in the container of my choice.

Answer (score 0):

In your button click event you can access the image selected in the FileUpload control:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileUpload.//Get you image and check if it is correct

    BlobService upload = new BlobService();
    upload.UploadBlob(<<give the image filestream to your upload server>>);
}
```

You UploadBlob should have a stream as input (the file image).

Answer (score 0):

In the button click event, you need to create the stream and then upload the same to WCF service.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BlobService upload = new BlobService();

    System.IO.FileStream streamToUpload = new System.IO.FileStream(FileUpload.PostedFile.FileName, 
               System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read)
    upload.UploadBlob(streamToUpload );
}
```

Code of the `UploadBlob` service method should look like below:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "UploadBlob", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]

public void UploadBlob(Stream fileStream)
{
    // Connect to the storage account's blob endpoint 
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("BlobConnectionString"));
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

    // Create the blob storage container 
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");
    container.CreateIfNotExists();

    // Create the blob in the container 
    CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("nature");
    blob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);

}
```